# gofstat results: AD and KS tests

Tags: r

I'm using gofstat function of fitdistr package to run the Anderson-Darling and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests. My results are (p=0,05):

```
$chisq
[1] 11.64559

$chisqbreaks
V149    V113     V12    V133    V152    V157    V146    V127 
0.00001 0.00341 0.00461 0.00571 0.00681 0.00931 0.01161 0.01601 

$chisqpvalue
[1] 0.07035865

$chisqdf
[1] 6

$chisqtable
       obscounts theocounts
<= 1e-05   12.000000   8.613365
<= 0.00341  8.000000  10.913812
<= 0.00461  8.000000   5.108425
<= 0.00571  8.000000   5.114935
<= 0.00681  8.000000   5.385660
<= 0.00931  8.000000  12.362122
<= 0.01161  8.000000  10.182407
<= 0.01601  8.000000  12.960688
> 0.01601   9.000000   6.358586

$ad
[1] 1.449119

$adtest
[1] "rejected"

$ks
[1] 0.1278385

$kstest
[1] "not rejected"
```

My question is: How do I know the AD and KS are rejected? Searching on the web I've found http://www.eridlc.com/onlinetextbook/index.cfm?fuseaction=textbook.appendix&FileName=Table7 with a KS table and for `n=77` the max value of D is 0.15.... But shouldn't the program also return the max D value and the equivalent for the AD? What's the puropose of giving the KS and AD values and not their maximum values? My apologies if I'm failing to see something obvious. Thanks!

EDIT:
If you use `gofstat` be aware to use `adk.test` and `ks.test` as well to compare the results. And use a large number of values with `adk.test` and bootstrap as well since the results vary a lot.
In my case the `gofstat` AD test was rejected for the Normal but using `adk.test` it was not... `p-values` around 0,20 (n=100000)....

Comment: What was the answer given on Cross Validated? The question does seem to belong there, but it's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for.

Comment: The answer was: "chisquare is not rejected, AD is and KS is not". Thanks but I also can read :) What I want to know is how the program knows the AD is rejected and the KS is not.

Comment: At a 95% confidence level, the KS test is not rejected because the p-value is greater than 0.05. I am not familiar with the Anderson–Darling test, but the interpretation is likely analogous. EDIT: I do think this question belongs at Cross Validated, since it doesn't appear to have to do with the software per se.

Comment: Where do you see the p-value of the KS? and of the AD test? that's the question. Tha it happens what you say it is obvious. But I'd like to know the values....

Comment: I apologize. I read the output incorrectly. Looking at the documentation for `gofstat`, in the `fitdistrplus` package, it doesn't appear that the p-value is provided for the KS or AD tests, only the decision and value of the statistic. If you need the actual p-values, the `ks.test` function will work. For the AD test, it looks like there is one available in the `adk` package.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `ks.test`, regarding adk I'm having troubles because if I use it needs two samples, so I use `adk.test(pnorm(rnorm(1000)), data)` where `data` is a list with my data and the outcome is `p-value =0`....

Comment: If I use `adk.test(rnorm(n), rnorm(n))` it gives me decreasing values of `p` for increasing values of `n`, so if we have a large number of values two almost identical distributions are rejected by the AD... weird! Actually it varies: it could be 0.02 or 0.6 independent of `n`... even weirder!

Comment: None of that is weird. (1) `p` *should* decrease for increasing `n` -- we have greater power to reject the null hypothesis (even for trivial differences) with larger `n`, and (2) `p` is a random variable -- in the null case it's uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.  If these things don't make sense you should either ask on CrossValidated or (preferably) re-read some basic statistics ... (not meaning to offend, but these are really basic ideas from statistics ...)

Comment: Ok Thanks, but what's the value of a test if for very large `n` (a condition which most people would find ideal) it is likely that the test will always reject the null hypothesis? or what's the rationale of chosing `n`? too low can be very innacurate, too high maybe not informative.... right?

Comment: well, `n` is usually the size of the data set you have -- not something you can choose.  There is indeed a controversy over the value of GOF testing ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless gives one discussion (while focused on testing normality, most of the arguments there apply more generally to GOF testing).  The question one generally wants to ask is **not** "can I detect a difference between my data and distribution `x`" but "is the difference between my data and distribution `x` big enough to matter for my purposes?"

Comment: AH I see, thanks for this! But now `p` really changes a lot between tries of `adk.test`. I'll probably have to run it a few times and get an average value or a 5% quantile out of the results. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  But (as I mentioned above), having `p` change a lot between runs of `ad.test` is exactly what you'd expect if the null hypothesis is true ... `summary(replicate(100,ad.test(rnorm(100))$p.value)): Min.=0.002602,  1st Qu.=0.200800,   Median=  0.488200    Mean=0.479200,  3rd Qu.=0.719300,     Max. 0.997000`  If I were you I would take the observed p-value as a good guess at the GOF and proceed from there.

Comment: OK but take for instance your example, you are doing a AD test for a Normal distribution using data generated from a Normal distribution and you still have a lot of variability (0.997 to 0.0026).... it can either be on the spot or way off! It's hard for me to just take a single value and to justify it.

Comment: @jpcgandre, as I said, that's **exactly** what you should expect, and it has exactly the right long-term properties: the null hypothesis will be rejected 5% of the time ... perhaps you can post on CrossValidated to get a better way to do what you want to do ... ?